# Window Rot Repair and Replace Exterior Wall Beam Under Siding

Tags: exterior, siding, replacement, beam, rot

[image]I'm hoping to get some suggestions about how to repair a double stud that runs vertically next to an exterior window. The window frame was covered with metal flashing so I didn't notice all the water that was seeping through until there was quite a bit of rot. The rot extended through the corners of the frame and the stool and apron.
I know I'll need to rebuild and repair this.

Also, I have a vinyl siding exterior but I've got hardboard siding underneath it. So, the water and rot went through the hardboard, through the sheathing rotted this double beam. So, now I'm left with an open exterior wall leading up to the window. Next to the window I still have the vinyl, hardboard, tar paper, osb and insulation.

I need to replace the rotted double stud next to the window as it is very weak and deteriorated 70% through. Do I need to replace the entire stud?

A local contractor said that he doesn't need to go all the way up but the entire bottom is rotted so I don't see how.  I think I can do the repairs myself but I'm unsure of the best path here.

If I do need to replace the entire thing, what is the easiest way to do that? Do I need to pry through the layers? Cut through them with a Sawzall?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please attach a pic or two that illustrate the scenario, interior and exterior? If you can't do it, place the pics on Imgur and post links to them in your question or in a comment; we will add the pics for you.

Comment: Most definately a picture is needed... And a vertical beam??? Perhaps you mean a stud or studs, perhaps a king stud with a jack stud beside it? Beams are typically run horizontal.

Comment: Studs, sorry. For some reason the first pic attempt didn't go through. But here goes...

Comment: At a minimum, I'd suggest you need to pull back enough siding to expose the king & jack studs until they're clean and rot-free to see how much needs to be replaced. It also looks like you've got damage on both sides. I hope you've created some sort of at least minimally water-resistant temporary cover for the back side of that interior outlet below the window that's exposed to the elements until your repair is finished.

Comment: Yes, I've had this entire wall and window covered with plastic sheeting. I guess one of my primary questions is really whether or not it is possible to only replace only the lower half of the jack and king studs if the upper half turn out to be rot free?